# Buying localized Playstation 4 games in US Playstation Store

Tags: psn, ps4

If I buy a game in the US Playstation Store that has been localized for another country will I be able to use the localization.

For example: "Lego: The Hobbit" can be purchased locally with Danish translation and I assume that is the version, I would get if I purchased it in the Danish Playstation Store.

If I purchase it in the US Playstation Store, will I still be able to play it in Danish?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your console's language is set to Danish and the game supports Danish localization, the game will be in Danish.

If your console is set to a language that is not included in your game, the game will run in the first language listed in the game's metadata, which appears to be sorted alphabetically according to their English abbreviation (i.e. GER for "German" instead of DE for "Deutsch").
More specifically: if your console is set to English and you try to launch a game that has been localized only in German, French and Italian, the game will run in French forcing others to set their console's language to German or Italian unless they can live with French localization.

Only very few games allow you to set the language instead of relying on the console's language and falling back to some weird default in case of failure; *Metal Gear Solid 5: Ground Zeroes* is one such game, although it is a bit of a special case. You can specify the language for everything text based, such as subtitles and menus, but not for voice-overs. The game is either voiced in Japanese for the Japanese version, or in English for the International version.

---

In short: Yes, if the version you bought features Danish localization, you can play the game in Danish, but only if your console's system language is set to Danish as well or the game allows you to set the language manually.

Comment: To clarify: My question is if the versions that are sold on the US Playstation Store will feature Danish localization if versions that are sold in physical stores and/or the Danish Playstation Store are localized. Neither the US nor the Danish store has any information about language support that I can find.

Comment: @RasmusFaber I'm afraid I can't answer that point in particular. My guess is that the digital version is identical to the disc version, except for the couple of bits to determine if it's a disc version or a digital one, but I'm not entirely sure about that. All I know is that all the games I could download this far were playable in English and I'm using the CH store, so I can choose between German, French or Italian, but not English. Considering CH has 4 national languages, it wouldn't be surprising if they were treated somewhat differently from the rest (although it would still be unlikely)

Comment: @RasmusFaber The original answer is correct, but more to your point. I can confirm that the digital versions are the regional versions. For instance I have US and JPN accounts on my PS3.


I have a US PSN game with Japanese and English language options, but the JPN PSN download only features Japanese (since the US version was localized and distributed after the fact). So if I wanted to play this in English, I would have to play the US release only.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the game.

Technically and logistically it would be easier to have just one game for all markets, but sometimes e.g. English is stripped from Russian versions, because that game is cheaper on the Russian market and the distributor wants to hinder that it is imported cheap from elsewhere on “rich markets”.

And sometimes they launch at different times, either for economical reasons or because translation work has not finished yet...